# How to apply Fable/Forecast (in R) to this database?

Tags: r, database, time-series, forecasting, fable

I am trying to forecast a multiple time series with the Fable function in R. It seems the most eficient way to do it, but I am very new using R so I'm currently dealing with a lot of problems. I just wanted to ask someone for advices and Ideas. I already found how to do it just using the forecast function package, but in a way that requires a lot of extra steps.
My data is an excel with 5701 columns and 50 rows. Each Column as the name of a product in the first row and the next 49 values are numbers, representing the sales from January 2017 to January 2021. First, how to transform that table into a tsibble? I know I need to do that in order to work with Fable, but I'm stuck in such a simple step. Then I would like to have as output a table with the monthy forecast for the next 3 semesters (april 2021 to september 2022) with Product|Date|Model Arima(values)|error of arima(value/values)|model ETS|Error of ETS|model Naive|error of naive..etc. My main objective is to get a table with product|best prediccion for april2021/september2021|best prediccion for october2021/march2021|best prediccion for april2022/september2022|

What I was doing was using this code:

```
newdata <- read_excel("ALLINCOLUMNS.xlsx")
Fcast <- ts(newdata[,1:5701], start= c(1), end=c(49), frequency=12)
output <- lapply(Fcast, function(x) forecast(auto.arima(x)))
prediction <- as.data.frame(output)
write.table(prediction, file= "C:\\Users\\thega\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\finalprediction.csv",sep=",")
```

Which gave to me, by default, something in the format |product1.Point.Forecast||Product1.Lo.80||Product1.Hi.80|Product1.Lo.95|Product1.Hi.95|Product2.Point.Forecast|...|Product5071.Hi.95|... anyway, I dont need the 80 and 95 intervals, and that made more difficult to me to work in excel with it. How to get something in the format:
|point forecast product 1|point forecast product 2|....|point forecast product 5701|, showing only the forecast? I know that I have to use level=NULL in the forecast function, but it is not working in the ways I had tried. I was planning to do a programming to delete those columns but it is less elegant. Finally, is there any way to show all the errors for the methods in a column? I want to add to my table the best method so I need to verify which as the less error.

Answer (score 2):

The {fable} package works best when data is in a tidy format. In your case, the products should be represented across rows instead of columns.
You can read more about what tidy data is here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html
Once you've done that, you can also read about tidy data for time series here: https://otexts.com/fpp3/tsibbles.html

Without having your dataset, I can only guess that your `Fcast` object (the `ts()` data) looks something like this:

```r
Fcast <- cbind(mdeaths,fdeaths)
Fcast
#>          mdeaths fdeaths
#> Jan 1974    2134     901
#> Feb 1974    1863     689
#> Mar 1974    1877     827
#> Apr 1974    1877     677
#> May 1974    1492     522
#> Jun 1974    1249     406
#> Jul 1974    1280     441
#> and so on ...
```

That is, each of your products have their own column (and you have 5701 products, not only 2 I'll use in an example).

If you already have the data in a `ts` object, you can use `as_tsibble(<ts>)` to convert it to a tidy time series dataset.

```r
library(tsibble)
as_tsibble(Fcast, pivot_longer = TRUE)
#> # A tsibble: 144 x 3 [1M]
#> # Key:       key [2]
#>       index key     value
#>       <mth> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 1974 Jan fdeaths   901
#>  2 1974 Feb fdeaths   689
#>  3 1974 Mar fdeaths   827
#>  4 1974 Apr fdeaths   677
#>  5 1974 May fdeaths   522
#>  6 1974 Jan mdeaths  2134
#>  7 1974 Feb mdeaths  1863
#>  8 1974 Mar mdeaths  1877
#>  9 1974 Apr mdeaths  1877
#> 10 1974 May mdeaths  1492
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Setting `pivot_longer = TRUE` will collect the columns into a long format. This format is suitable for the `{fable}` package. We now have a `key` column which stores the series name (product ID for your data), and the values are stored in the `value` column.

With the data in an appropriate format, we can now use auto `ARIMA()` and `forecast()` to obtain forecasts:

```r
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
as_tsibble(Fcast, pivot_longer = TRUE) %>% 
  model(ARIMA(value)) %>% 
  forecast()
#> # A fable: 48 x 5 [1M]
#> # Key:     key, .model [2]
#>    key     .model          index        value .mean
#>    <chr>   <chr>           <mth>       <dist> <dbl>
#>  1 fdeaths ARIMA(value) 1980 Jan N(825, 6184)  825.
#>  2 fdeaths ARIMA(value) 1980 Feb N(820, 6184)  820.
#>  3 fdeaths ARIMA(value) 1980 Mar N(767, 6184)  767.
#>  4 fdeaths ARIMA(value) 1980 Apr N(605, 6184)  605.
#>  5 fdeaths ARIMA(value) 1980 May N(494, 6184)  494.
#>  6 fdeaths ARIMA(value) 1980 Jun N(423, 6184)  423.
#>  7 fdeaths ARIMA(value) 1980 Jul N(414, 6184)  414.
#>  8 fdeaths ARIMA(value) 1980 Aug N(367, 6184)  367.
#>  9 fdeaths ARIMA(value) 1980 Sep N(376, 6184)  376.
#> 10 fdeaths ARIMA(value) 1980 Oct N(442, 6184)  442.
#> # … with 38 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can also compute forecasts from other models by specifying several models in `model()`.

```r
Fcast <- cbind(mdeaths,fdeaths)
library(tsibble)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tsibble'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, union
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
as_tsibble(Fcast, pivot_longer = TRUE) %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(value), ets = ETS(value), snaive = SNAIVE(value)) %>% 
  forecast()
#> # A fable: 144 x 5 [1M]
#> # Key:     key, .model [6]
#>    key     .model    index        value .mean
#>    <chr>   <chr>     <mth>       <dist> <dbl>
#>  1 fdeaths arima  1980 Jan N(825, 6184)  825.
#>  2 fdeaths arima  1980 Feb N(820, 6184)  820.
#>  3 fdeaths arima  1980 Mar N(767, 6184)  767.
#>  4 fdeaths arima  1980 Apr N(605, 6184)  605.
#>  5 fdeaths arima  1980 May N(494, 6184)  494.
#>  6 fdeaths arima  1980 Jun N(423, 6184)  423.
#>  7 fdeaths arima  1980 Jul N(414, 6184)  414.
#>  8 fdeaths arima  1980 Aug N(367, 6184)  367.
#>  9 fdeaths arima  1980 Sep N(376, 6184)  376.
#> 10 fdeaths arima  1980 Oct N(442, 6184)  442.
#> # … with 134 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The `.model` column now identifies the model used to produce each forecast, of which there are 3 models.

If you want to focus on point forecasts side by side, you can `tidyr::pivot_wider()` the forecast `.mean` values across several columns.

```r
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(tidyr)
Fcast <- cbind(mdeaths,fdeaths)
as_tsibble(Fcast, pivot_longer = TRUE) %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(value), ets = ETS(value), snaive = SNAIVE(value)) %>% 
  forecast() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("key", "index"), names_from = ".model", values_from = ".mean")
#> # A tibble: 48 x 5
#>    key        index arima   ets snaive
#>    <chr>      <mth> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 fdeaths 1980 Jan  825.  789.    821
#>  2 fdeaths 1980 Feb  820.  812.    785
#>  3 fdeaths 1980 Mar  767.  746.    727
#>  4 fdeaths 1980 Apr  605.  592.    612
#>  5 fdeaths 1980 May  494.  479.    478
#>  6 fdeaths 1980 Jun  423.  413.    429
#>  7 fdeaths 1980 Jul  414.  394.    405
#>  8 fdeaths 1980 Aug  367.  355.    379
#>  9 fdeaths 1980 Sep  376.  365.    393
#> 10 fdeaths 1980 Oct  442.  443.    411
#> # … with 38 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can learn how to evaluate accuracy of these models/forecasts here: https://otexts.com/fpp3/accuracy.html

Comment: Brooo...What a beatiful lovely soul. You literally made my entire day. It worked perfectly and I am almost ready with it.  Also your book and your work is incredible helpful, and I have learned a lot. A last question, if you can. Where should I put (in the last example) the augment function to get something in the format key|index|value|arima|.fitted|.resid|.innov|ets|.fitted|.resid|.innov|snaive|.fitted|.resid|.innov|? I haven´t worked so much with the %>%  so this is a bit new. Thank so much again.

Comment: `augment()` is used on model objects to add info onto the original data. `data %>% model() %>% augment()`.
In order to compare the output in a wide format, you can again use `pivot_wider()`. While wide formats are nice to display in tables and to compare values by eye, a longer format is better for plotting. You may find plotting these values more informative.

`as_tsibble(Fcast, pivot_longer = TRUE) %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(value), ets = ETS(value), snaive = SNAIVE(value)) %>% 
  augment() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ".model", values_from = c(".fitted", ".resid", ".innov"))`